# Are the cognates of PIE roots in this paper reliable?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, roots, cognates

I came across a long [**paper**](https://www.academia.edu/20225819/Genesis_of_the_Proto-Indo-European_Roots) with many cognates of PIE roots, some examples:

1. *weid- "to see" and ***s**ueid- "to shine" < *weid-**es**-weid-,
2. *h₂ǵ- "to drive" and ***s**h₂ǵ- "to seek" < *h₂ǵ-**es**-h₂ǵ-,

where *-s- is an **interformant** in both examples.

Due to my lack of knowledge of judging or proving PIE cognates, I would like to find out whether these cognates are true or not.

Comment: Your examples aren't cognates; cognates are words in different languages that descend from the same word in the ancestor language. Are you asking whether the specific roots you list in the question are widely accepted?

Comment: If so, *weid- "see" and *h₂eǵ- "drive" are common and uncontroversial, but *sueid- "shine" is marked as doubtful in LIV (the IE verb root dictionary), and *sh₂(e)ǵ- is not listed at all.

Comment: Why do you want s to be an "interformant" rather than a prefix?

Comment: Hi @TKR ! I find *seh₂g- at [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/seh%E2%82%82g-), which has an alternative reconstruction *seh₂ǵ-

Comment: @TKR, cognate used here is to mean the etymological relation among PIE roots, and as you say, these 2 examples are wrong, but this paper gives much more pairs of such relations, which seems worthy to evaluate, so I want to know how many of them are reliable.

Comment: Hi @fdb, the word **interformant** I use here is from page 3 of that paper, where the author uses another word **preformant**  that I also don't understand.

Comment: I think the reason you're not getting answers is that your question basically boils down to "Is this paper's argument correct", which is more a prompt for discussion than an easily answered factual question.

Comment: @TKR, you are right, this is indeed a paper review question, the paper I linked here is really interesting to read, and the method of connecting multiple PIE roots is impressive, although maybe not very convincing. In conclusion, I feel like finding an paper review answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, extensions are… no one knows what exactly they are or whether they really exist. They look like suffixes, because they are encountered at the final position of what one thinks is the Proto-Indo-European root. The problem with them – I mean the extensions (élargissements, Erweiterungen etc.) – is that it is impossible to define their functions or meanings. Some clever blokes try to speculate that they modify slightly the meaning of the root and therefore may be called determinatives. Benvenist went as far as trying to explain them as ordinary suffixes, but this attempt of his failed, like his root theory, too. There is another major problem to that. Some roots, or what linguists believe to be such, are nowhere detected without extensions, like, for instance, *gen-, allegedly meaning ‘to pinch’ – look it up in IEW. This makes us question the correctness of the reconstruction *gen-.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is not whether PIE had preformants and interformants, but that the preformants are in fact suffixes and "extensions".

Comment: Could you clarify this for readers without a background in this issue? What is an 'extension', and what kind of evidence suggests your analysis?

Comment: Basically, extensions are… no one knows what exactly they are or whether they really exist. They look like suffixes, because they are encountered at the final position of what one thinks is the Proto-Indo-European root. The problem with them – I mean the extensions (élargissements, Erweiterungen etc.) – is that it is impossible to define their functions or meanings. Some clever blokes try to speculate that they modify slightly the meaning of the root and therefore may be called determinatives.

Comment: Benvenist went as far as trying to explain them as ordinary suffixes, but this attempt of his failed, like his root theory, too. There is another major problem to that. Some roots, or what linguists believe to be such, are nowhere detected without extensions, like, for instance, *gen-, allegedly meaning ‘to pinch’ – look it up in IEW. This makes us question the correctness of the reconstruction *gen-.

Answer (score -2):

argument is not correct if not impossible, such word forming was never in proto-indo-european not even earlier, and proto-indo-european was a suffixional language, didn't have 'preformants" "interformants ", and only had s- mobile as kind of prefix, hence this argument is not tenable. indo-european verbs existed as the main root and some kind of very old determinative postpositional consonantal extensions which may have been in pre-proto-indo-european with a particular meaning.

Comment: The author of the paper in question does not pretend PIE had prefixes. He claims that the prefixes (or preformants) are suffixes. Their position at the beginning of the root is an illusion: the beginning is in reality the end, because the root is factually a reduplication, which lost its first part (preceding the suffix) due to the word stress. The first part of the reduplication remains more or less intact, if stressed, s. examples in https://www.academia.edu/30677337/Greek_ γέφῡρα and_Armenian_ կամուրջ “bridge”